# Breakout game as cool as Krypton Egg

Tags: windows-7, game

I've been looking for a breakout game. The last breakout game I played was [Krypton Egg](http://www.dosgamesarchive.com/download/krypton-egg/) in 1996. I've never seen such a cool breakout game since that time, although it should be much easier developing cool games nowadays, shouldn't it?

Which one's your favorite breakout game in Krypton Egg class?

It

- may cost money (yeah, I'm willing to support that guy who provides that super class breakout game)
- must run on Windows 7 x64
- may even use a mid class 3D graphics card, if that really helps (although CPU power is already at a factor 24 since then)

Please do me a favor, if you don't know Krypton Egg: watch the video first. Do not suggest simple Arkanoid clones. I'm really looking for a high quality game. There are thousands of clones which cannot keep up with Krypton Egg.

**Warning**: do not download Krypton Egg from that site to run in DOSBox. It has a strange certificate ("Just accept") and is detected as unwanted program by VirusTotal.

**Update**

So what features does the game need to be that cool?

- Fast paddle movement (not that slow pixel by pixel movement)
- Mouse paddle control (since keyboards are laggy and unprecise)
- 2D paddle movement (possibly triggered by some bonus)
- Massive multi-ball (I see 3 almost everywhere, so there should be 20 or more possible)
- at least 20 different types of bonuses, one of them must be shooting
- the same amout of maluses
- better than sinewave sound

The game may

- use an emulator such as DOSBox, if that helps. Make sure it matches the system specs below.

System specs:

- Intel core i5
- 16 GB RAM
- NVidia GeForce 8400 GS
- AMD Radeon HD 7700

Comment: Hi, here on SR we have specific rules for [game development](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51/are-video-game-related-questions-on-topic/224#224) Also you might want to read [this discussion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-alternatives) to get an idea on how to ask questions that ask for alternatives. Currently the information about what you are looking for are on YouTube. It would serve the site better if they were here.

Comment: Does it have to run natively on Windows 7? [Arkanoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkanoid) for example is orginally an arcade game, but it can be played on PC using an NES-emulator

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: ok, I understand. I've updated the question, hopefully matching the site now.

Comment: @Timmy: emulators are ok. See also the updated question. If you want to post that as an answer, please state where to get the emulator and a (legal, if not free) copy of the game.